# How can I implement a simple "jump" action with three.js and/or Physijs?

Tags: physics, jumping, three.js

Assume I have a simple Physijs object like [this car](http://chandlerprall.github.io/Physijs/examples/constraints_car.html).  How can I adapt something like this to "jump" (hydraulics ftw!) when pressing spacebar for instance?

I'm currently thinking [`applyCentralImpulse`](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/blob/1558502ab27819d7dea2c395598eeeb30478cb5c/physi.js#L999) should come into play.

Comment: Ah, well it looks like you found the answer at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the documentation is apparently non-existent at this point, but searching the source yields the following:

```
applyCentralImpulse = function ( force )
```

So, create a vector pointing up, `upVector.set( 0, jumpFactor, 0 );`, then use `applyCentralImpulse` to the vehicle to make it jump.

Alternatively, you can use `applyImpulse ( force, offset )` and supply an offset to position the force under the front wheels, thereby giving your hydraulics "the win".

Comment: I'll give it a shot and report back.  As you pointed out, documentation is comparable to that of three.js, so who knows.